# I dont see the correct path in google to miniventas.com

Tags: angular, hosting

I have hosting in firebase call
miniventas.com (connected).

Now when i type miniventas.com
I see https://ventas-1c4d4.web.app/. why ?, It should show the correct dot com.

Any help please, I dont know how to solve it.

stackoverflow is telling me that I need to tipe 220 chrs, my question is short !